# warning when http://*/* is included in manifest

Tags: permissions, google-chrome-extension, warnings

What will be the warning displayed when I try to install an extension that has `http://*/*` permission in manifest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html

`"Your data on all websites"` will be the warning. Check out the link for the complete list.

[edit]
In addition to the link I provided, the actual question was what would the end user see. @Alasdair answered that in a comment with this link:

http://www.google.com/support/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186213

...that shows exactly what the user would see.

Comment: Exactly right! Also, it's worth having a look at this documentation too.

http://www.google.com/support/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186213

Comment: @Alasdair - Great link! That is the answer the OP was looking for I think. He specifically asked what will be displayed. Repost it as an answer.

Comment: I have no problem with you adding this link to your answer.